# How to detect if object is an array in DML compile time?

Tags: dml-lang

There are set of SIM_is_xxx methods - but they are run-time. Can I check if object is an array compile-time?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `SIM_is_xx` is relevant for Simics configuration objects, which is a separate domain compared to operating with DML at compile-time. Can you clarify exactly what you need?